# Akka EventsourcedBehavior JournalFailureException but stack trace doesn't show underlying cause

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I have an akka persistence app (EventSourcedBehavior based actors, akka 2.6.13) and using akka-persistence-jdbc 3.5.3 for the journal/snapshot plugin along with a cockroachdb cluster. Things work fine, but recently I've seen a lot of event persist failures but the error logs do not show any underlying cause of the issue - no SQL level exceptions in the trace at all. At the same time as this, we usually see errors due to actors being restored, and the journal again throwing JournalFailureExceptions, but no underlying reason.

If I can't see any underlying reasons (the only thing the logs show is `async write timed out after 5.00 s` (is this timeout value configurable?) does this mean there is something else causing the issues, unrelated to the journal plugin implementation or database? How can I debug this further - i've examined the message handler in my EventSourcedBehavior that has failed when persisting an event to see if is doing anything weird or blocking, but I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Any ideas welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JournalFailureException`s likely indicate connectivity or slow responses from the DB.  If it's just slowness, scaling out/up the cockroach cluster might help.

"async write timed out after" is from cluster sharding's remember-entities feature ([that's the only occurrence in Akka](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/7abc41cf4e7e8827393b181cd06c5f8ea684e696/akka-cluster-sharding/src/main/scala/akka/cluster/sharding/Shard.scala)) which also indicates connectivity issues or slow responses from the DB.

There is most likely no problem with your behaviors.  It's worth noting that remember-entities (especially in `eventsourced` mode... `ddata` mode is a little better in this regard if you're OK with not remembering entities across full-cluster restarts) itself puts a substantial load on persistence and your DB and is consistently (if you have more than a few hundred entities) counterproductive, in my experience.  Unless you've actually tried disabling it and seen an actual net negative effect, I suggest disabling remember-entities.

Comment: Thats very interesting about remember-entities - I wonder if this is actually what is tripping the circuit-breaker causing the Effect.persist calls to all fail-fast. I had assumed it was the other way around. I have been using eventsourced mode for remember-entities because I did want to survive full cluster restarts - but maybe switch to ddata. I increased the timeout for akka.cluster.sharding.updating-state-timeout to 10s to see if it helps when things go slow.

Comment: Remember entities is not required to survive full cluster restarts. Not inherently anyway. Think of remember-entities as eagerly reloading entities synchronously rather than lazy loading them as needed. As Levi said, remember-entities actually makes surviving a cluster restart much harder because eagerly loading won't scale past a tiny number of entities.

Comment: @DavidOgren the reason for my use of remember-entities feature is so that actors that are using timers can re-spawn and setup their timers again when they are migrated from one shard to another during a cluster restart - our app requires that the actors "time out" a job if they have not received a response by a certain time. However the more I look at this the less I like the use of non-persistent timers using the scheduler. DData mode might be ok so long as we only ever perform a rolling cluster restart, otherwise a rethink of our logic will be required.

Comment: For that situation, I would suggest moving the entity restarting logic to a domain-specific cluster singleton which can bring entities back in a prioritized order without preventing new entities from being started.  Assuming the "should this entity be resurrected" question can be answered from the events being persisted, you can feed that using a persistence query.